# PHP Uploading Files issue

Tags: php, file-upload

**Updated!**

I have never had a problem with this before, i'm on a local server and UAC is turned off as well.

Here is my form, well, a dumbed down version of the form as there is a lot of text in there:

```
<form id="setup" name="setup" action="php/process_setup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="cname" id="cname" value="" />
   <input type="text" name="splash" id="splash" />
   <input type="file" name="file"/>
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
   <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_setup" />
</form>
```

Here is the PHP im trying:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
```

And here is the result:

> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\php\process_setup.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\php\process_setup.php on line 16 Upload:
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\php\process_setup.php on line 17 Type:
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\php\process_setup.php on line 18 Size: 0 kB
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\php\process_setup.php on line 19 Stored in:

**Edit 2**

Just did a test to see if PHP has write permission, here is the code:

```
echo copy("1383778885275.jpg", "C:/xampp/tmp/1383778885275.jpg");
```

And the result was:

> 1

And the image IS in the tmp directory..

Comment: I don't know why you're using `&& isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])` because the `tmp` file doesn't exist "yet". So of course it will fail.

Comment: first step is to see if your initial if statement is being passed, are all of those isset and !empty correct?

Comment: `empty()` checks if variable is set as well, so `isset()` is not needed

Comment: I believe @Fred-ii is incorrect. Since you are if POSTING the FILE the FILE exists and has a `tmp_name`. But you should change `'!empty($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` to `isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`.

Comment: Updated my post using w3schools code, still no luck.

Comment: I am aware of w3schools' upload examples and you're using the wrong one. If anything, use the 2nd one, however there are better examples out there. @MartynLeeBall

Comment: The temp folder for uploads is C:\xampp\tmp, but that folder is empty, shouldn't it show up in there?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing it in on a simple way , try having this:

```
if(!empty($_POST) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"]) ){ //check the following post values if not empty
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $temp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $location= "../images/";
    if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $location.$name)) {
        echo "Uploaded!!!";
    } else {
        echo "Error:";
    }
} else {
    echo "Please choose a file to upload";
}
```

Comment: where's your condition when post values have established?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change `!empty($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` to:

```
isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]
```

and `if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $location.$name)) {` to:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $location.basename($name))) {
```

Emphasis on `basename()`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your notice information ,the `$_FILES` is probably empty.You can check the following issues:

```
1.Make sure your directory has permissions for the tmp and upload directories.
2.Make sure the value of `file_uploads` option in `php.ini` is `On`
```

Comment: I have checked '2' and that is set to 'On'.

Comment: @Martyn Lee Ball ,well then that will be a permission problem.

Comment: I have also checked '1', but I can't see any additional users to give full access permission to. Currently: Authenticated users; SYSTEM; Administrators; Users. All have Full control..

Comment: @@Martyn Lee Ball ,another point,how about the size of your uploading file?php.ini also has a default limit.usually 8M by default.

Comment: I have checked that,it's only an image and doesn't go over that limit.

Comment: how about the disk usage?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41065/discussion-between-martyn-lee-ball-and-young)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys. It seems that there was an issue in some of the code I didn't include.. :/

Basically:

```
<form id="setup" name="setup" action="php/process_setup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

.....

....

<input type="file" name="logo"/>

...


.....

somewhere had some dodgy code I deleted

....

</form>
```

Thanks for the help.